# Connect android app to wamp

Tags: android, mysql, web-services, wamp

I want to insert the data in mysql from android. I use php webservice for transfer the data.

Which url is used to transfer the data? Which method is used for android webservice?

Comment: you have an android app and webservice and through that webservice  you want to communicate with mysql database

Comment: where you are getting problelm? be specific and try to give code so you can get more help

Comment: host may not be null exception occur...

Comment: can you please post code how you are accessing webservice from you app?

Comment: i think you have not given any host name while writing connection to the mysql

Comment: refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible as best as i know android. You need use PHP or J2EE running as your using already Wamp, and expose as apis.

Comment: refer this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Yeah as said,you  have to write some php code and expose as api. Call that api from android http requests with parameters ( sql database operation + data). Make sure server is running as it should handle request and make according db call. According to operation performed you set results and send back android client. Here PHP code will handle db calls and operations.